# Erro de compilação em código no Unity

Tags: c#, .net, unity3d

[image: SS]

esta asim

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    void Awack()
    {
            floorMask = LayerMask.GetMask ("Floor");

            anim = getComponet <Animator> ();
            playerRigidbody = GetComponent <Rigidbody> ();
    }

    void FixedUpdate ()
    {

        float h = Input.GetAxisRaw ("horizontal");
        float v = Input.GetAxisRaw ("vertical");

        Move (h, v);
        Turning ();
        animating (h, v);
    }
     void (float h, float v)
        {
                movement.Ser(h,0f,v);

                movement = movement.normalized * speed * Time.deltatime;

                playerRigidbody.MoviPosition (transform.position + movement);
        }
    void Turnig ()
    {
                Ray camRay = Camera.main.screenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

                RaycastHit floorHit;

        if(Physics.Raycast(camRay,out floorHit.camRayLenght.floorMask))
        {
            Vector3 playerToMouse = floorHit.point - transform.position;
            playerToMouse.y = 0f;

            Quaternion newrotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(playerToMouse);
            playerRigidbody.MoveRotation(newrotation);

        }


    }


    void animating(float h,float v)

    {
        bool walking = h != 0f.v!=0f;

        anim.SetBool("IsWalking",walking);





    }

}
```

Comment: @mauricio-s-c-vedoy, Bem vindo ao StackOverflow PT (SOPT) faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para conseguir entender qual a melhor forma de perguntar e de responder.

Comment: Se você for postar aqui cada erro mínimo de digitação que você encontrar vai ficar difícil te ajudar. Essa eu até entendo que não seja tão óbvio mas postar erro porque falta um `;` é exagerado.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

Fica difícil ajudar só com isto mas uma coisa que está errada com certeza é isto: `bool walking = h != 0f.v!=0f;`. Este problema específico provavelmente resolve assim:

```
void animating(float h, float v) => anim.SetBool("IsWalking", h != 0f || v != 0f);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Other/UnityAnimation.cs).

O código está mal organizado e dificulta a leitura.